# Large byte arrays over RMI

Tags: java, serialization, rmi, data-transfer

I'm currently trying to find out whether it's a good idea to transfer rather large byte arrays (<50MB) over RMI.

I read that it is slow and the data needs to be hold in memory both on the client and the server. This could result into a problem when there are multiple calls.

Are there any (simple) alternatives to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMI is intended to transfer objects.  If you have a byte array object on the server and want it on the client you must have it both places until it has been delivered successfully (then you can let the original go away).

A more reasonable approach might be repeated calls populating a remote object transferring only a small chunk at a time.  This will then in turn require multiple trips making it slower.

What is the actual (non-technical) problem you want to solve?

Comment: User uploads. The business logic is on the backend so the whole data needs to be transferred. This is rather a _best practice_ question or said differently, transfer at once or in chunks! :)

Comment: If you are in a web-scenario anyway then consider using a http-file-upload solution.  Otherwise you have a byte stream representing the image anyway, upload it in chunks.

Comment: Web-scenario, aye. I use http-file-upload, then progress in the frontend and finally need to send the data to the backend (which is a different server).

Comment: if the frontend and backend are "close" anyway, then just do it.

Answer (score 3):

[RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/)  lets  you stream objects in chunked fashion.

EDIT : you can also use [KRYO](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/) to serialize and compress the object to send across the wire.

Comment: I have not used RMIIO but have used KRYO compressed serialization and sent across objects via Redis and MessageQueues. You can use kryonet( http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/ ) which is used to send objects via the network using Kryo

Answer (score 1):

Consider java streams which support compression to send/receive large amounts of data.

For instance [GZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) to send data and [GZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) to receive sent data block.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very bad idea. The byte array has to be formed in memory before calling the remote method; then it has to be transmitted in the call; then it has to be read by the server; then it has to exist in the server; then it can be processed by the server. You never want to deal with data items this large in a single chunk. It wastes both time and space. Consider a streaming API where you can use moderate sized buffers at both ends; send the data in chunks that are convenient to the sender; and receive it in chunks that are convenient to the receiver.

Comment: So you suggest I should use frameworks like RMIIO? I'm a bit surprised that there is not a more basic solution for this (I guess) common problem of distributed systems.